Messages in kafka contains weird starting characters in dotnet when consuming
I have a json topic with no schema in kafka, hosted on confluent. When I consume the topic it seems like it has added 0x00 to the beginning of the string or something. Where does that come from and what can I do about it? As it is now I can't deserialize it without trying to remove those bytes, but they shouldn't be there in the first place.

Can you share more details about the producer? Was json schema serializer  used? I doubt dotnet is the problem. Could you try with kafka-console-consumer or kcat?

If you are using docker to host kafka, kafka-cat commandline tool will nicely format those weird metadata characters. For more info checkout this:-  https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafkacat/
